# Erro ORA-01460 no Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, procedure

Tenho a procedure abaixo:

```
PROCEDURE GRAVA_(P_IMEI_DISPOSITIVO IN NVARCHAR2,
                              P          LONG,
                              P_DET      LONG,
                              RETORNO_OPERACAO   OUT VARCHAR2)
```

Nos parâmetros P e P_DET recebo strings com dados em XML, e dentro da procedure converto para XML. Conforme abaixo:

```
PL_MZ_CAB_XML           SYS.XMLTYPE;
PL_MZ_CAB_XML := SYS.XMLTYPE.CREATEXML(P);
```

Quando recebo arquivo maiores que 32.000 Bytes o Oracle está me retornando a mensagem abaixo:

> Ora-01460: conversão não-implementada ou não resolvível solicitada.

O que posso fazer para resolver isso?
Tenho que mudar o tipo do meu parâmetro será?

Answer (score 1):

Você não falou a respeito da versão do seu Oracle, mas provavelmente ela é inferior a 10.1.0.5. Esse erro ocorre em versões mais antigas do oracle. Outro possivel problema é o driver do JDBC desatualizado.

uma outra solução é usar o tipo de dado como CLOB.